# Url Routing for unknown number of params

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, custom-routes

I have seen this post: [MVC Handler for an unknown number of optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371615/mvc-handler-for-an-unknown-number-of-optional-parameters) but it's for MVC and doesn't seem to work for me as I get an error:

```
A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
```

I want to be able to have an indeterminate amount of params in a Url, I have the following route:

```
RouteCollection.MapPageRoute("ManyParam", "{*params}.html", "~/Default.aspx");
```

This also seems to trigger the error message above.

How can I set up a route to have an unknown number of parameters in web forms (not MVC).

I am trying to achieve the following urls:

```
www.example.com/some-thing.html
www.example.com/some-thing/else.html
www.example.com/and/some-thing/else.html
www.example.com/1/2/3/4/5/6.html
```

**EDIT**

It seems to work when I use the following:

```
RouteCollection.MapPageRoute("ManyParam", "{*params}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

The problem is with this is that it doesn't allow the `.html` at the end.

Comment: Can you show how your desired Url look like? Your `"{*params}.html"` does not make it very clear what you want to achieve...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - That would of been useful ... Added, thanks.

Comment: Try `"{*path}"` for Url and have some sort of [constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) that will require `.html` at the end using 5 arguments override of [MapPageRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992978.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I have tried that: `RouteCollection.MapPageRoute("ManyParam", "{*path}.html", "~/Default.aspx");` but I get the error: `A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.` Am I doing something wrong with the `.html` at the end?

Comment: I tried to add rough sample as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested route below - the wildcard one have to be absolutely last portion of Url. So to force ".html" at the end you need to use constraint (5th argument).

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "ManyParam",
    "{*path}",
    "~/Default.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "path", @".*\.html" } }
 );
```

Comment: Isn't that MVC though? I don't have a controller.

Comment: @webnoob - edited to probably be more correct - the point is you have to use constraint since you can't have anything past wildcard segment.

Comment: Right Ok, that falls in line with my tests I have been running. I will look up constraints with web forms and see what I can do. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Works perfectly (with a slight tweak to the syntax). Many thanks again for your time.