# How to use laravel routing for unknown number of parameters in URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

For example, I'm publishing books with chapters, topics, articles:

`http://domain.com/book/chapter/topic/article`

I would have Laravel route with parameters:

`Route::get('/{book}/{chapter}/{topic}/{article}', 'controller@func')`

Is it possible, in Laravel, to have a single rule which caters for an unknown number of levels in the book structure (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481484/url-routing-for-unknown-number-of-params))? This would mean where there are sub-articles, sub-sub-articles, etc..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need are optional routing parameters:

```
//in routes.php
Route::get('/{book?}/{chapter?}/{topic?}/{article?}', 'controller@func');

//in your controller
public function func($book = null, $chapter = null, $topic = null, $article = null) {
  ...
}
```

See the docs for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have unlimited number of parameters after articles, you can do the following:

```
//in routes.php
Route::get('/{book?}/{chapter?}/{topic?}/{article?}/{sublevels?}', 'controller@func')->where('sublevels', '.*');

//in your controller
public function func($book = null, $chapter = null, $topic = null, $article = null, $sublevels = null) {
  //this will give you the array of sublevels
  if (!empty($sublevels) $sublevels = explode('/', $sublevels);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Clarified question. I meant where there are an unlimited number of levels after `{articles}`. I.e. `/sub-article/sub-sub-article/` etc etc.