# make laravel 5 generate seo friendly url after submit

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have search form which pass GET parameter, so in url its like

```
http://www.example.com/list/item?&qs=&unit-type=Office&min-bed=&max-bed=&min-price=&max-price=
```

so search result is shown with such ugly url, I want to make this url seo friendly, I don't want to use post method.

Is there any .htaccess code that can help to make seo friendly url of such get parameter.

I tried this .htaccess code but doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681750/how-to-use-laravel-routing-for-unknown-number-of-parameters-in-url) will help you with your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by SEO friendly? It is not clear if you are looking to use `/` instead of `&` or if you want a way to use parameters with forward slashes.

Comment: I want to use parameters with forward slashes

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is possible, but shouldn't be done.

The page is not a static page, or a product page, or a listing page. It is a search result page.

The search result page should not be `SEO friendly` in terms of the url containing information about the search query because this is supposed to be dynamic. A search engine will not be interested in indexing a specific user's search result page on your website. A search engine will be interested in indexing the search page.

If you are looking to have a product listing page for example with pre-defined search queries, then why not just create a specific controller and for the time being, manually write an SEO friendly url to point to the required method on that controller?

e.g.

`Route::get('offices-between-10000-and-20000-pounds', 'ListingController@getOfficesBetweenPriceRange');`