# how construct route pattern for an unknown number of tags - Laravel & Conner/Taggable

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, tagging, custom-routes

I have a blog and a quotationfamous sayings repository on one site. 
The quotations are tagged and the entries are tagged too. 
I use this [rtconner/laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging) package.

Now, what I want to do is to display ALL `Quotation` models which share the same tags as article.

The Eloquent syntax is simple, as the original docs provide an example:

```
Article::withAnyTag(['Gardening','Cooking'])->get();
```

#### possible solution

Optional routing parameters. The asker-picked answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31681869/4209866) gives a solution:

```
//in routes.php
Route::get('/{book?}/{chapter?}/{topic?}/{article?}', 'controller@func');

//in your controller
public function func($book = null, $chapter = null, $topic = null, $article   = null) {
...
}
```

#### my problem

In my app the shared tags might count more than 3 or 5. I will soon get an example with even 10 tags. Possibly more

### My question

Does it mean that I have to construct an URL with 10 optional routing parameters? Do I really need sth like this:

```
Route::get('quotations/tags/{tag1?}/{tag2?}/{tag3?}/{tag4?}/{tag5?}/{tag6?}/{tag7?}', 'controller@func');
```

### my question rephrased

I could create a form with only a button visible, and in a hidden select field  I could put all the tags. The route would be a POST type then and it would work. But this solution is not URL-based.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could process the slashes, as data:

```
Route::get('quotations/tags/{tagsData?}', 'controller@func')
    ->where('tagsData', '(.*)');
```

Controller:

```
public function controller($tagsData = null)
{
    if($tagsData) 
    {
        //process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my solution. As I have a tagged model, I dont't need to iterate through tags in url to get the whole list of tags.

The enough is this:

```
// Routes file:
        Route::get('quotations/all-tags-in/{itemtype}/{modelid}', 'QuotationsController@all_tagged_in_model');
```

Then in my controller:

```
public function all_tagged_in_topic($itemtype, $id) {

    if($itemtype == 'topic') {
        $tags = Topic::find($id)->tags->pluck('name')->all();
        $topic = Topic::find($id);

    }
    if($itemtype == 'quotation') {

        $tags = Quotation::find($id)->tags->pluck('name')->all();
        $quotation = Quotation::find($id);

    }
    // dd($tags);

    $object = Quotation::withAnyTag($tags)->paginate(100);;
```

And it is done.

Now, the last issue is to show tags in the URL.
TO do that, the URL should have an extra OPTIONAL parameter `tags`:

```
// Routes file:
        Route::get('quotations/all-tags-in/{itemtype}/{modelid}/{tags?}', 'QuotationsController@all_tagged_in_model');
```

And in the `{url?}` part you can just write anything which won't break the pattern accepted by route definition.
In your view you might generate an URL like this:

```
// A button to show quotes with the same set of tags as the article

// generated by iteration through `$o->tags`
<?php
$manual_slug = 'tag1-tag2-tag3-tag4`;
?>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('quotations/all-tags-in/article/'.$o->id.'/'.$manual_slug) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-tags icon"></i> Tagi:

    </a>
```