# ASP.NET MVC: Have total control over the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website that has nested categories. I would like the categories to be in the url such as something like this

http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Component_Frameworks/NET/Chats_and_Forums/

as you can see in the above url the categories are in the url itself. How can I develop something like this in asp.net mvc?

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332782/asp-net-unknown-length-mvc-paths/1332841#1332841 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107507/asp-net-mvc-custom-route-handler-constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch them as parameters {*id} then parse them in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [URL Routing](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-23-cs.aspx):

As per the above, you'll just need to add a route(s) to the routing table using placeholders in your URLs for your categories / sub-categories etc. This means any links to your pages, or anyone directly writing in the URL will go to the routing table and try to match it up - make sure the default 'catch-all' route is last in your list of routes defined.

When you're building up these URLs for links etc to click in your views, then I would probably [create a Html helper](http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/mvc/tutorial-09-cs.aspx) that builds up a string with your controller/category/sub-category syntax.