# MVC Routing Engine routes same formatted route to different controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Okay, I did my homework and search SO, and indeed I found *similar* questions but not reporting the behavior I'm getting.

Here is the deal, I have defined a route:

```
routes.MapRoute("CategoryName", "Category/Name/{text}",
    new { controller = "Category", action = "Name", text = "" });
```

The twist here is the following:

This url: `http://www.url.com/Category/Name/existingCategoryName`

And *this* url: `http://www.url.com/Category/Name/anotherExistingCategoryName`

Both url's **should** go to the same controller method which is `public ActionResult Name(string text)` but sadly the first url is going to the default `Index` method, the second is being routed correctly.

I wonder why this happens, as I've been with .net mvc for several years and never experienced this behavior.

As a side note here are some facts:

- As it's being route to different methods, I doubt the code inside them has something to do with it.
- When manually write the category to something it doesn't exists in the DB as a category name it goes through the `Name` method.
- The routes are placed correctly, as I'm aware the first route that matches the pattern will win.
- Even I tried place the `CategoryName` route first, the behavior is the same.
- When writing each link in the `Category/Index` I use the same `@Html.RouteLink()` helper, so all the links are formatted the same way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a) other routing rules prior to the "CategoryName" one, and b) an example of how you're writing the @Html.RouteLink()

Comment: There are not any routing rules above "CategoryName". The RouteLink is being written as follows: `@Html.RouteLink(item.Name, "CategoryName", new { text = item.Name })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `-` sign in the failing route?

Maybe you can find more information with the [Routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

And maybe you can look at this question: [Failing ASP.NET MVC route. Is this a bug or corner case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279040/failing-asp-net-mvc-route-is-this-a-bug-or-corner-case)

Phil Haack also give an possible answer to your problem in: [ASP.NET routing: Literal sub-segment between tokens, and route values with a character from the literal sub-segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318373/asp-net-routing-literal-sub-segment-between-tokens-and-route-values-with-a-cha)

Comment: Based on your information I reproduced your case, the routing seems to work. Is it possible to share some more code?